# SQL Server : CASE does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT 
   a.componentId, a.uniqueCode, 
   'sd'= CASE 
            WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(b.name)) IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(b.uniqueCode)) IS NULL 
               THEN isnull(b.uniqueCode,'')+isnull(b.name,'') 
            WHEN RTRIM(LTRIM(b.name)) IS NULL AND RTRIM(LTRIM(b.uniqueCode)) IS NULL
               THEN isnull(b.uniqueCode,'')+isnull(b.name,'')
            ELSE b.uniqueCode + '(' + (b.name) + ')'
    END, 
    a.specialization 
FROM Doctors a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Territories b ON a.locationId = b.componentId;
```

Suppose `b.uniqueCode = T003` and `b.name = Dhanmondi 01`, then `sd` should be `T003(Dhanmondi 01)`.

Now if `b.name = NULL` then sd should be `T003`, but my query result shows `T003()`.

What is wrong my T-SQL query?

Comment: Wild guess: Have you been working with Oracle before converting to SQL-Server? :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that b.name is `null`? If it has an empty string instead of `null` you would have the result you see. BTW, the `rtrim/ltrim` stuff is totally unnecessary when checking with `is null` and your second `when` will never happen because you will always end up in the first `when` if either column is `null`.

This will treat empty strings as null:

```
SELECT a.componentId, a.uniqueCode, 'sd'=
        CASE 
            WHEN nullif(b.name, '') IS NULL OR nullif(b.uniqueCode, '') IS NULL 
            THEN isnull(b.uniqueCode,'')+isnull(b.name,'') 
            ELSE b.uniqueCode + '(' + (b.name) + ')'
        END , a.specialization 
FROM Doctors a LEFT OUTER JOIN Territories b ON a.locationId = b.componentId;
```

Comment: +1 for `NULLIF()`, noting that `NULLIF(REPLICATE(CHAR(32), @n), '')` will result in `NULL` for all non-negative values of `@n`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's sort some basics out first...

Your second `WHEN` is impossible to reach, since the earlier `WHEN` will always be `true` (either null) before the second `WHEN` (both null).

`RTRIM()` and `LTRIM()` will only return `NULL` if the argument is `NULL`, so these two condition expressions are identical:

- `RTRIM(LTRIM(b.name)) IS NULL`
- `b.name IS NULL`

Removing redundant code, including the unreachable `WHEN`, will let you simplify your code considerably:

```
CASE
    WHEN b.name IS NULL OR b.uniqueCode IS NULL 
        THEN isnull(b.uniqueCode,'') + isnull(b.name,'')
    ELSE b.uniqueCode + '(' + b.name + ')'
END
```

Now that we can read it...

The most likely explanation is that `b.name` is *blank*, not `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL and all of the popular SQL products - except Oracle - a `NULL` and an empty string `''` are two different things. So, you should be checking both options:

```
SELECT a.componentId, a.uniqueCode, 
    CASE 
        WHEN b.name IS NULL OR b.name = ''
            THEN COALESCE(b.uniqueCode, '')
        WHEN b.uniqueCode IS NULL OR b.uniqueCode = ''
            THEN b.name
            ELSE b.uniqueCode + '(' + b.name + ')'
    END AS sd
     , a.specialization 
...
```

or to remove leading and trailing spaces:

```
    CASE 
        WHEN b.name IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(b.name)) = ''
            THEN COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(b.uniqueCode)), '')
        WHEN b.uniqueCode IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(b.uniqueCode)) = ''
            THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(b.name))
            ELSE RTRIM(LTRIM(b.uniqueCode)) + '(' 
               + RTRIM(LTRIM(b.name)) + ')'
    END AS sd
```

Comment: "In all RDBMS - except Oracle..." -- The relational model has no concept of nulls. Perhaps you meant, "In all of the popular SQL products - except Oracle..."

Comment: @onedaywhen: Can *RDBMS* not be a synonym of *SQL product* in some contexts (particularly, in that phrase)? (I do not mean to argue, just want to clarify that for myself.)

Comment: @AndriyM : I guess the point was that pure relational DBMS would not have any concept of NULL.

Comment: @ypercube: I thought as much. My question is about something different. For me, it was clear that by *‘all RDBMS’* you meant *‘all (the popular) SQL products’*. I'm now interested to know whether it is correct to use ‘RDBMS’ as a synonym of ‘SQL product’ *at all*, for I sometimes do use ‘RDBMS’ with that particular meaning.

Comment: @AndriyM: Strictly speaking, SQL and RDBMS are mutually exclusive (SQL operates on tables which are not relations). But let's for argument's sake say, loosely speaking, that 'all popular SQL products' is a subset of 'RDBMSs'. Even then, why use the superset term 'RDBMS' which includes non-SQL products when we know from the context that we are definitely talking about a SQL product? However, 'RDBMS' is not a synonym for 'SQL product' because of the existence of RDBMSs that are not SQL products.

Comment: @onedaywhen: The *tables are not relations* statement somewhat worries me, though. I would say that, while not *being* relations, they *represent* relations. Otherwise what is so relational about 'all popular SQL products' that allows us to consider them a subset of RDBMSes?

Comment: @onedaywhen: Never mind, I'm [looking into it](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22tables+are+not+relations%22).